# CSS - can I use @font-face like this:

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I want to use fonts url from another website, is it possible?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'font';
    src: url('http://example.com/font.eot?#') format('eot'),    
         url('http://example.com/font.woff') format('woff'),     
         url('http://example.com/font.ttf') format('truetype');  
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I tried this but it doesn't work!

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot import a font *file* from another URL, as it [violates cross origin specs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). You would have to put the css file in the same directory on that domain(`http://example.com/fonts.css`):

```
/*fonts.css*/

@font-face {
    font-family: 'font';
    src: url('font.eot?#') format('eot'),    
         url('font.woff') format('woff'),     
         url('font.ttf') format('truetype');  
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Then in your stylesheet, import it:

```
@import url("http://example.com/fonts.css");
```

Or, link to it in your document `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/fonts.css">
```

Comment: Thanks it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't** import any script or font from other server if the respective has disabled [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) in configuration.

**Only** if you have acces to that another server, you can enable it in the following way:

```
# Microsoft IIS in web.config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>

# Apache config
# The code can be placed with the `.htaccess` file or `httpd.conf` file:
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>

# nginx config
if ($filename ~* ^.*?\.(eot)|(ttf)|(woff)$){
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

This sets the  **Access-Control-Allow-Origin CORS** configuration to allow pulling from all domains.  List specific domains by comma if you want to serve fonts up to only specific domains.  You'll want to serve up all font types appropriately in the case that the browser prefers one type.

Read further: [Serving Fonts from CDN](https://davidwalsh.name/cdn-fonts)